# Shortening cross-references in Sphinx documentaton

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

When using the intersphinx extension to cross-reference objects from external Python packages the references can get pretty long if the module the object is defined in is nested several layers deep. Specifically I'm working with the Sympy library which leads to constantly having to type things like `` :class:`sympy.core.symbol.Symbol` `` all over the place.

I know that you can:

1. Prepend a `~` character to the reference to make the link only appear as "Symbol" in the generated documentation.
2. Truncate the path from the *beginning*, leaving a dot at the beginning, like `.Symbol`, `.symbol.Symbol`, `.core.symbol.Symbol`, etc.
3. Just use `Symbol` and count on Sphinx to find it, if I know there won't be any conflicts.

#1 is fine for the generated documentation but is still very verbose in the source files. #2 and #3 are shorter but leave out the most important part, which is the actual root package.

Is there a way shorten references in a way that removes the intermediate module names but also keeps the root package namespace? Something like `sympy.*.Symbol` or `sympy::Symbol`?

Comment: Assuming you set intersphinx to use the name `sympy` for the documentation set, and that the intersphinx object exists, did you try `:class:BACKTICKsympy:SymbolBACKTICK`? Comments don't allow nested backticks.

Comment: @StevePiercy I did try that but it did not work. After some debugging I found out that Intersphinx does recognize this format and looks specifically in the inventory named by the part before the colon, but then tries to match the part after the colon against the fully qualified keys in the inventory without the usual processing (so `:class:'sympy:.Symbol'` doesn't work either (single quotes subbed for backticks).

Comment: I think you could work around it by registering a callback for the `missing-reference` event. When I tried my handler was getting called after intersphinx's handler for the same event had processed it, and it modifies `node['reftarget']` in-place to remove the colon and the part before it so that information is lost.